# Joining objects together causes textures to change

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have a cake I have made which are three different objects:

[image]

I would like to join these three objects into one, but here's how it looks when I join them:

[image]

What can I do to prevent the loss of detail (especially for the strawberry)?

I have attached the blender file if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 2 materials you're using a *Musgrave Texture* but with no *Texture Coordinate* node before it, by default this kind of procedural texture will be projected as *Generated*, which means that the proportions of the objects will be taken into account. When you'll join the objects the new object will have a different proportion (it will be higher), therefore the deformation of the texture. To fix that, create a *Texture Coordinate* and a *Mapping* node before your *Musgrave Texture* nodes, choose the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* (which won't take the proportions of the object into account), tweak the Scale values of the *Mapping* node.